# insertion and deletion in the table of objective C

Tags: objective-c

I am wondering, I have an empty table and I want to display a text in that table, then I want to clear that text when the table has been inserted with something else. And the text will appear again when I completely remove everything in the table again.?

Comment: You may want to add an iPhone tag since the method calls are a bit different for NSTableView on OS X.

Answer (score 1):

In your dataSource for your UITableView there is a method:

```
-tableView:objectValueForTableColumn:row:
```

In that method you can check your NSArray or whatever you have supplying data to your table to see if there are any entries. If there are none and the request is for row zero, column zero, just return your 'no data' string.

To clarify syntax, assume you have an NSArray named songs which you wish to print:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    //boilerplate cell production
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

    //check if we have data to supply, if not set message to "No Songs Available"
    //otherwise print the name of the song in each cell
    if (indexPath.row == 0 && indexPath.section == 0 && [songs count] == 0)
        cell.textLabel.text = @"No Songs Available";
    else if (indexPath.row < [songs count])
        cell.textLabel.text = [(Song *)[songs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] songName];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I would like to know the syntax, i am quite confused about the syntax in objective C. I am actually still abeginner

Comment: Here's a good resource for Objective-C syntax: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html